# C program to mimic gdb call function to execute on core

Tags: c, gdb, coredump

In my program, IP prefixes are stored as a Trie.  I would like to dump the trie from linux coredump generated by the program.  I already have a C function which traverses through the tree and prints the prefixes stored in Tree.  However, using gdb I can't dump the trie by calling this function.  Is it possible to write a program to load the core and call this function by linking the library which dumps the Trie. ( I am thinking of using Python gdb module, but that would require me to convert the C program to Python).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to write a program to load the core and call this function by linking the library which dumps the Trie. ( I am thinking of using Python gdb module, but that would require me to convert the C program to Python).

Sure: you can build your source into a shared library, wrap your shared library into Python and have Python load and call it.

But it likely much easier to convert your C program into plain Python instead.